# Prob. 39, Chap. 7, in Schaum's GENERAL TOPOLOGY: The images of sets of a basis of the domain space under an onto open map ...

Tags: general-topology, open-map

Let $(X, \mathscr{T})$ and $\left(Y, \mathscr{T}^*\right)$ be topological spaces, let the function $f \colon (X, \mathscr{T}) \longrightarrow \left(Y, \mathscr{T}^*\right)$ be open and onto, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for $\mathscr{T}$. Then how to show that the collection
$$
\big\{ f(B) \colon B \in \mathscr{B} \big\} \tag{0}
$$
is a basis for $\mathscr{T}^*$?

My Attempt:

Let $V$ be any open set in $\left( Y, \mathscr{T}^* \right)$. We need to show that $V$ can be expressed as a union of some sets in the collection (0) above.

Since $f$ is onto, we have
$$
V = f \left( f^{-1}(V) \right).
$$

And, since $f$ is open, each set $f(B)$ in the collection (0) above is also an open set of $\left(Y, \mathscr{T}^* \right)$.

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Are you perhaps missing some assumptions? I think this is not true as is. If $f$ is the identity map, $\mathcal{T}$ is the trivial topology and $\mathcal{T}^*$ is the discrete topology, this should not hold.

Comment: If one assumes that $f$ is both continuous and open, then $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, so $f^{-1}(V) = \bigcup \{B \in \mathscr B : B \subseteq f^{-1}(V)\}$ and so $V =\bigcup \{f(B) : B \in \mathscr B, B \subseteq f^{-1}(V)\}$.